# error: The remote name could not be resolved: 'info@myemail.ir' c# asp.net

Tags: email, send

i want to send mail programatically with my website and i cant do this.
this is my code

```
MailMessage sendMailMessage = new MailMessage();
            sendMailMessage.From = new MailAddress("info@myemail.ir", "");//esb@ertebatsanatbazar.ir
            sendMailMessage.To.Add(txtemail.Text);
            sendMailMessage.Bcc.Add(txtemail.Text);
            sendMailMessage.Subject = "وبسایت تبلیغاتی";
            string mailBody = "کاربر گرامی سلام؛ از اینکه وبسایت ما را برای تبلیغات خود انتخاب کردید متشکریم کد فعالسازی حساب کاربری شما:" + vercode.ToString();
            sendMailMessage.Body = mailBody;
            sendMailMessage.IsBodyHtml = true;
            NetworkCredential netCredential = new NetworkCredential("info@myemail.ir", "****");
            SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("info@myemail.ir", 25);
            smtpClient.EnableSsl = true;
            smtpClient.Credentials = netCredential;
            smtpClient.Send(sendMailMessage);
```

and get following error:

> The remote name could not be resolved: 'info@myemail.ir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

finally it work with this:

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("myserver.com", 25);
```

thank you pasilda

Comment: My issue was mail.myserver.com. Changing it to myserver.com worked. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is with this line:

`SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("info@myemail.ir", 25);`

See the MSDN documentation here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/67w4as51(v=vs.110).aspx where the first argument of the SmtpClient constructor is the server, not an email address.

Try something like the SMTP server address for your ISP (something like smtp.myserver.com) or an IP address:

```
SmtpClient smtpClient = new SmtpClient("smtp.myserver.com", 25);
```